# Failed to connect instance with ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudformation

I'm trying to build a system like this one:

[image: click here]

I can't connect to the Instance in private public through ALB. I checked my cloudformation code several times and still couldn't find problem. Please help me.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Metadata:

  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:

    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
         default: "system"

Parameters:
  KeyNameA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName



  SSHLocation: 
      Type: String
      MinLength: 9
      MaxLength: 18
      Default: 0.0.0.0/0
      AllowedPattern: (\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})


Resources:

  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.1.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: True
      EnableDnsHostnames: True
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-VPC

  InternetGateway: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway 
    DependsOn: VPC 



  AttachGateway: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment 
    Properties: 
      VpcId: !Ref VPC 
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway



  PublicSubnetA: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet 
    Properties: 
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.1.10.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: True 
      Tags: 
      - Key: Name 
        Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Public-A



  PublicSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.1.30.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs ] 
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: True
      Tags: 
      - Key: Name 
        Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Public-B



  PrivateSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.1.20.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: False
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ] 
      Tags: 
      - Key: Name 
        Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Private-A



  PublicRouteTable: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable 
    Properties: 
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags: 
      - Key: Name 
        Value: Public 




  PublicRoute:  
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route 
    DependsOn: AttachGateway 
    Properties: 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0 
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway


  PrivateRouteTable: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable 
    Properties: 
      VpcId: !Ref VPC 
      Tags: 
      - Key: Name 
        Value: Private 



  PrivateRoute: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route 
    Properties: 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0 
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NATGateway


  NATGateway: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway  
    Properties: 
      AllocationId: !GetAtt ElasticIPAddress.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA 


  ElasticIPAddress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP 
    Properties: 
      Domain: VPC



  PublicSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation 
    Properties: 
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable


  PublicSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation 
    Properties: 
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetB 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable


  PrivateSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation 
    Properties: 
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetA 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable



  TargetGroup:  
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup  
    Properties:  
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Name: WebInstanceTargetGroup  
      Protocol: HTTP  
      Port: 80  
      TargetType: instance  
      Targets:  
      - Id: !Ref WebInstance  
        Port: 80  



  ALBalancerSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: SG for ALBSG 
      GroupName: ALBSG
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp 
        FromPort: 80 
        ToPort: 80 
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0 


  ALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: PublicALB  
      Scheme: internet-facing  
      IpAddressType: ipv4  
      Subnets:  
        - !Ref PublicSubnetA
        - !Ref PublicSubnetB
      SecurityGroups:  
        - !Ref ALBalancerSG  

  Listener:  
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener  
    Properties:  
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ALB  
      Port: 80  
      Protocol: HTTP  
      DefaultActions:  
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup  
          Type: forward  



  WebInstanceSecurityGroup: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup 
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: SG for WebInstance 
      GroupName: WebSG
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp 
        FromPort: 80 
        ToPort: 80 
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0 
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref  ALBalancerSG
      - IpProtocol: tcp 
        FromPort: 22 
        ToPort: 22 
        CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation



  WebInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      BlockDeviceMappings: 
      - DeviceName: /dev/sda1 
        Ebs: 
          VolumeSize: 8 
          VolumeType: gp2
      DisableApiTermination: false
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceTypeParameter
      KeyName: !Ref KeyNameA
      ImageId: ami-02b7cfebf005c915d
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref WebInstanceSecurityGroup
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetA




  PrivateSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.1.90.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ] 
      Tags: 
      - Key: Name 
        Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Private-B


  PrivateSubnetC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.1.110.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs ] 
      Tags: 
      - Key: Name 
        Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Private-C



  PrivateRouteTableRDS: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable 
    Properties: 
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags: 
      - Key: Name 
        Value: Private2



  PrivateRouteRDS: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route 
    Properties: 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTableRDS
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0 
      InstanceId: !Ref WebInstance



  PrivateSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation 
    Properties: 
     SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetB 
     RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTableRDS



  PrivateSubnetCRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation 
    Properties: 
     SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetC 
     RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTableRDS



  DBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: DBSubnetGroup for RDS instances
      SubnetIds:
        - Ref: PrivateSubnetB
        - Ref: PrivateSubnetC



  RDSSGIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress 
    Properties: 
      GroupId: !GetAtt VPC.DefaultSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp 
      FromPort: 5432
      ToPort: 5432
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0 



  DBMasterInstance: 
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties: 
      DBInstanceIdentifier: DemoRDS
      DBName: MyRDS
      AllocatedStorage: 10
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      StorageType: gp2
      Engine: postgres
      EngineVersion: 11.4
      MasterUsername: DBUser
      MasterUserPassword: DBPassword
      PubliclyAccessible: False
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt VPC.DefaultSecurityGroup
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup



  DBReplicaInstance: 
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties: 
      DBInstanceIdentifier: DemoReplica
      AllocatedStorage: 10
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      SourceDBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBMasterInstance
      SourceRegion: ap-northeast-3
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems with your CFN template:

1. The RDS subnets have default route pointing to the Web instance - I doubt you want to do that. Generally you'll only have **2 or 3 Public subnets** using IGW for 0.0.0.0/0 and **2 or 3 Private subnets** using NAT GW for 0.0.0.0/0. All your instances and databases should be in the Private subnets and the ALB should be in the Public subnets.
2. When you create the Web instance like the template says it **doesn't have a web server running**, hence nothing listens on port 80 and in turn the ALB sees the instance as unhealthy. That's why you're getting "502 Bad gateway" or something like that.

   Ideally you'd install and start the web server through the instance UserData on boot. That way the ALB will see that it's running and will start sending traffic to it.
3. As it is you've got no way to SSH to the Web instance as it sits in the private subnet. Typically you'd also create a **Jump host** in the public subnet that you can SSH to and/or VPN to, or configure **Systems Manager** on the Web instance so you can open a **[SSM Session](https://aws.nz/projects/ssm-session/)** to it without using a jump host. You'll need an EC2 role for it.

That should give you some pointers for start. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I added a Jump host and connect to my instance successfully. But I'm still not very understand if I avoid to connect  RDS subnets to the Web instance, how can I direct the traffic from Web instance to the RDS subnets?